# Computing Test Loss in Kernel Ridge Regression

Tags: regression, loss-functions, ridge-regression, kernel-trick

In Kernel Ridge regression we have the standard loss function $$L(\beta) = \|Y-K\beta\|_2^2 + \alpha \beta^T K \beta$$
Here, $K$ is the kernel (gram) matrix.

If I compute $\beta$ on a training set, so that $K$ is the train gram matrix, how do I then compute the test loss, assuming I want to include the regularization term in the test loss? Should I replace both occurrences of $K$ in $L(\beta)$ with the test version?